# php function on counting 30 days but no end week or holiday

Tags: php, function, date, calculator, days

i neeed help.

i need create php function on counting 30 days. But if the last day is a weekend or a holiday. So I have to add the days so that the last day was a working day. 30 days must not end on a weekend or a holiday.I searched for forums and google, but I did not find anything. I've found working days counting but not what I need. Thank you for your help.

```
          $holiday = array(
            '01-01',
            '01-06',
            '03-30',
            '04-01',
            '04-02',
            '05-01',
            '05-08',
            '07-05',
            '08-29',
            '09-01',
            '09-15',
            '11-01',
            '11-17',
            '12-24',
            '12-25',
            '12-26',
          );

          $count = 0;
          $temp = strtotime($row['prijem']); //example as today is 2016-03-25
          while($count<30){
              $newdate = strtotime('+1 day', $temp);
              $nextnewdate = date('m-d', $newdate);
              if(!in_array($nextnewdate, $holiday)){
                  $count++;
              }
              $temp = $newdate;
          }

          $end = date("d.m.Y", $temp);
```

start date is 24.05.2018, today. end date is 23.06.2018.

and now I need to always whenever the end date is a weekend or a holiday converted to a business day. So if the end date is Saturday, then the result will be on Monday 25.06.2018. And again, if it were a holiday to add more days on a business day.

Comment: You are expected to make an attempt to solve your problem yourself.  If you have not yet done so, you should now.  If you have, please include the code you have tried, explain the expected result, and the actual result, including any errors.

Comment: Get todays date parts (month, day, year) and create a new timestamp via `mktime()` and add 30 to the day.  Check the day-of-week for that day for saturday/sunday (and then do a brute force check against federal or religious holidays, etc if needed - there are APIs for this...) and if the resulting day isn't a business day add a day and check again.

Comment: it could work. And do you know the specific APIs? Or I can find it on the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for that loop since you only care if the 30th day is a business day or not (instead of caring if each day in between is).  Just add 30 days directly and then check the result.

```
$holidays = array(
            '01-01',
            '01-06',
            '03-30',
            '04-01',
            '04-02',
            '05-01',
            '05-08',
            '07-05',
            '08-29',
            '09-01',
            '09-15',
            '11-01',
            '11-17',
            '12-24',
            '12-25',
            '12-26',
          );

// the starting date, $row['prijem'] in your example
$temp = strtotime("2016-03-25");

// add 30 days to the starting date
$plus30days = strtotime("+30 days", $temp);

// while the end date is a holiday or weekend, add another day
// do this check until the end date is _not_ a weekend or holiday
while(in_array(date("m-d", $plus30days), $holidays) || date('N', $plus30days) >= 6)
{
    $plus30days = strtotime("+1 day", $plus30days);
}

echo date("d.m.Y", $plus30days);
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/705a48e2e8cae7a691719213ac6aa250abf7388c)

Comment: So it does. Deleted mine, you are the faster typist :)